# Kivy nested TabbedPanels unable to click on vertical tabs

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am attempting to create a nested TabbedPanel layout (in essence, you could think of it like a Battleship grid if that simplifies things). I have accomplished obtaining the visual representation that I want, however the vertical tabs of the nested TabbedPanel widget are unable to be clicked. This may be due to the fact that it resides within the parent TabbedPanel widget, and this may be interfering with the ability to trigger the `on_click` (or similar) property of the tabs themselves. I have provided a bare-bones example below.

I should also clarify that the content contained within the vertical tabs will dynamically change based on the selection of a different horizontal tab (along the top).

Any insight would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Python:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

#Load kv file
Builder.load_file('test.kv')

class Main_Panel(Screen):

    pass

class Nested_Panel(TabbedPanel):

    pass

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):

    pass

class TestingApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.sm = MyScreenManager()
        return self.sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestingApp().run()
```

kv:

```
<MyScreenManager>:

    Main_Panel:
        name: 'main'

<Main_Panel>:

    BoxLayout:

        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 20
        spacing: 20

        TabbedPanel:

            do_default_tab: False

            TabbedPanelItem:
                text: 'A'
                Nested_Panel:

            TabbedPanelItem:
                text: 'B'
                Nested_Panel:

            TabbedPanelItem:
                text: 'C'
                Nested_Panel:

        GridLayout:

            cols: 1
            size_hint: 1, .1

            Button:
                text: 'Quit App'
                on_release: app.stop()

<Nested_Panel>:

    do_default_tab: False
    tab_pos: 'left_top'

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: '1'

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: '2'

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: '3'

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: '4'

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: '5'

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: '6'
```

Comment: the click if it works, add different widgets to each TabbedPanelItem inside Nested_Panel and you will see that the selection changes, the effect is the one that is affected.

Comment: Got it. I guess the underlying issue for me then is that the currently active vertical tab for the corresponding active horizontal tab does not show a background highlight showing that it is indeed the tab that is currently selected

Comment: I am now thinking that my specific intent would better be suited by a ScrollView containing a box layout of toggle buttons that would dynamically change the content of each of the main tabs (avoiding the need for nested TabbedPanels). Thank you for your help @eyllanesc

Comment: That was my doubt, why do you use TabbedPanel? If you said a specific goal, maybe we could route you correctly. :D